# Getting user info Google-PHP-Client issue?

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

First, i just want to say what information i am needing to get from the user.

- Full Name (First/Last)
- Email Address (Main Account, not @google-plus.com)
- Location (Country, State, city, address)
- Youtube Username

To get all of this information, i went ahead and download/installed the PHP-Client Library located [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Since this is my first time using the API, i looked around and found the following scopes:

```
$client->setScopes(array(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
));
```

For some reason, when i run this: `$myData = $GoogleData->userinfo->get('me');` i get this:

`Undefined property: Google_Service_Plus::$userinfo in path/test.php on line 61`

Not too sure what i am doing wrong, or even if i should be using the Google Plus Api to get this information.

I need the Main Account email (Contains all youtube channels) and the users address, etc. That they signed up in their Google Account. How do i get this information and what am i doing wrong in my above example?

I have actually created a chat room dedicated to all things Google API ([Go here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48778/google-apis-php))

This also brings me to another point. Why is the documentation sooo outdated and not taken care of. Most of the examples that i see are from two years ago, but i am using something that has been updated a couple months ago.

Comment: Try creating the `Google_Service_OAuth2` service instead of Plus, and then try fetching from `$service->userinfo_v2_me` via a `->get()` call.

Comment: @ircmaxell What scope do i need to add Thank you. Ill let you know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Try checking out the source code. That's all I did (I'm not familiar with the API): https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php#L34

Comment: Yea, it did not give me the email i was looking for. Not the main account one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the new version of the PHP library (currently 1.0.4-beta [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)):

```
require_once 'lib/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'lib/Google/Service/Plus.php';

$google_client = new \Google_Client;
$google_client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$google_client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$google_client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI);
$google_client->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
$google_client->setAccessType = 'offline';

// Either call:
//     $google_client->authenticate($auth_code);
// with the $auth_code returned by the auth page or 
//     $google_client->setAccessToken($existing_token);
// with a previously generated access token.

$plus = new \Google_Service_Plus($google_client);
$person = $plus->people->get('me');

print_r($person);
```

The scope should be "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" (I only tested with the "profile" scope, because I don't have a Google Plus profile).

To get the YouTube channels, you'd have to add the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" and use the [channels#list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method, with the 'mine' parameter set to true. The class in the PHP lib is 'Google_Service_YouTube'.

Answer (score 5):

I hit a similar issue and solved it using version 1.1.4 of [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Assuming the following code is used to redirect a user to the Google authentication page:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('/path/to/config/file/here');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://redirect/url/here');
 $client->setAccessType('offline'); //optional
 $client->setScopes(['profile']); //or email
 $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
 header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 exit();
```

Assuming a valid authentication code is returned to the `redirect_url`, the following will generate a token from the authentication code as well as provide basic profile information:

```
 //assuming a successful authentication code is returned
 $authentication_code = 'code-returned-by-google';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 //.... configure $client object
 $client->authenticate($authentication_code);
 $token_data = $client->getAccessToken();

 //get user email address
 $google_oauth =new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
 $google_account_email = $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->email;
 //$google_ouath->userinfo->get()->familyName;
 //$google_ouath->userinfo->get()->givenName;
 //$google_ouath->userinfo->get()->name;
```

However, location is not returned. [New YouTube accounts don't have YouTube specific usernames](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1637615?hl=en-GB)