# How to retrieve the profile picture of a youtube channel (PHP)?

Tags: php, json, image, youtube, youtube-channels

So my page manages to connect the youtube channel via Youtube API and saves the token etc.. but i jut don't find any code example to retrieve the youtube profile picture.

I found another thread here from last year where someone answered with a json scrip. It looks as following:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YT_CHANNEL_NAME);
    string str = "thumbnail url='";
    string ImagePic = json.Substring(json.IndexOf("thumbnail url") + str.Length);
    if (ImagePic.Contains("'"))
    {
        ImagePic = ImagePic.Remove(ImagePic.IndexOf("'"));
        ImageChannel.ImageUrl = ImagePic;

    }
```

I don't have any experience in JSON and can't figure out if this still is a suitable code for me and how to implement it in my PHP code.

Comment: According to the documentation, you do have access to the profile image: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles?hl=en

Comment: Secondly this is server side JavaScript, Node.js basically.  You can't just directly translate that, it's too different scripting languages with their own implementations.  With that said, did you look into the php-youtube api framework?  You'll want to download that, also check the answer here for getting the user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117243/getting-user-info-google-php-client-issue

Answer (score 2):

This is how to get the profile picture from a youtube channel in PHP.

1, download the php api [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?hl=en)

2, get your [API key](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

4, you also need the channel ID, if it's your own account you can get it from [here](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced)

This is the php code

```
<?php

$DEVELOPER_KEY = 'YOUR_KEY';

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.  
require_once('/path/to/api/src/Google_Client.php');
require_once('/path/to/api/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
$htmlBody = '';
try {

    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
        'id' => 'CHANNEL_ID',
        'part' => 'snippet',
    ));


    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($channelsResponse);
    //echo '</pre>';
    $img = $channelsResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];

    echo "<img src='$img'>";

} catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}
echo $htmlBody;
?>
```

It's returned as a regular array and the docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), you can also use 'medium' or 'high' instead of the 'default'

Comment: Yep, and the new YouTube API is a bit of a pain. Super chatty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$channel_name = "DrIsrarAhmed_Official"; // replace with the name of the YouTube channel you want to fetch the profile picture of
$channel_id = ""; // initialize an empty variable to store the channel ID
$profile_picture_url = ""; // initialize an empty variable to store the profile picture URL

// Step 1: Get the channel ID by channel name
$api_key = "YOUR_KEY_HERE"; // replace with your YouTube Data API v3 API key
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&q=" . urlencode($channel_name) . "&key=" . $api_key;
$response = file_get_contents($url);

if ($response) {
  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  $channel_id = $data['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId'];
} else {
  echo "Error fetching data";
}

// Step 2: Get the profile picture URL by channel ID
if ($channel_id) {
  $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=" . $channel_id . "&key=" . $api_key;
  $response = file_get_contents($url);
  
  if ($response) {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    $profile_picture_url = $data['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
  } else {
    echo "Error fetching data";
  }
}

if ($profile_picture_url) {
  echo "<img src=\"$profile_picture_url\" alt=\"$channel_name's profile picture\">";
} else {
  echo "Error fetching profile picture";
}
?>
```